# find urls in string in Python duplicate

Tags: python, regex

Can someone help. As an example the following text output there more than pne hyper link. I’m looking for the first output: **JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000725**

```
Here are my output source and i look for these ones **https://www.zuora.com/apps/JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000725**

    https://www.zuora.com/apps/JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000726
https://www.zuora.com/apps/javascript:downloadTansactions("JournalEntries.dox?method=downloadTransactions&number=JE-00000726");
https://www.zuora.com/apps/AccountingPeriods.dox?method=view&id=2c92a0f949efde7f0149f05314e640b6
https://www.zuora.com/apps/ChartOfAccountsSetting.do?method=edit&id=2c92a0fb43812a1a0143980f213b7e34
https://www.zuora.com/apps/ChartOfAccountsSetting.do?method=edit&id=2c92a0fb43812a1a0143980f21507e39
https://www.zuora.com/apps/JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000725
https://www.zuora.com/apps/javascript:downloadTansactions("JournalEntries.dox
```

Comment: Please post your Python code with regex.

Comment: for link in soup.find_all('a', href =True):

Comment: You can use `url = link.split('"')[1]`.

Comment: @RicardLe please make your change in the question and show what output you got

Comment: I am looking for these so i use to + base url JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000725

Comment: Add your changes **INTO THE QUESTION**!!!

Comment: Hi Barak, i tried but Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscrap.py", line 21, in <module>
    url = link.split('"')[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Add your changes INTO THE QUESTION, it is unreadable otherwise and cannot be answered this way!!! Also, encapsulate every piece of code in your comments with ``.

Comment: Add the **ORIGINAL CODE**, not after trying my (or anyone else's) advice from the comments above. We were all speculating, because there was nothing to rely upon.

Comment: And if you want to add the output below the code, then please indicate that this is the output you're expecting. If you want a proper answer then please put some effort into posting a proper question!

Comment: Change `url = link.split('"')[1]` to `url = link.text.split('"')[1]`.

Comment: Hi barak,    url = link.text.split('"')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

I saved this in a file with name "url":

```
https://www.zuora.com/apps/JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000725**
https://www.zuora.com/apps/JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000726
https://www.zuora.com/apps/javascript:downloadTansactions("JournalEntries.dox?method=downloadTransactions&number=JE-00000726");
https://www.zuora.com/apps/AccountingPeriods.dox?method=view&id=2c92a0f949efde7f0149f05314e640b6
https://www.zuora.com/apps/ChartOfAccountsSetting.do?method=edit&id=2c92a0fb43812a1a0143980f213b7e34
https://www.zuora.com/apps/ChartOfAccountsSetting.do?method=edit&id=2c92a0fb43812a1a0143980f21507e39
https://www.zuora.com/apps/JournalEntries.dox?method=view&number=JE-00000725
https://www.zuora.com/apps/javascript:downloadTansactions("JournalEntries.dox
```

Now my code looks like:

```
import re
f = open ("url", "r").readlines()
for i in f:
    if re.search("JournalEntries\.dox\?method\=view\&number\=JE\-00000725",i): 
        print "found it !!"
```